# Pascal Arrays Output for my table is a bit screwed up

Tags: arrays, pascal

```
program Production5;

var machine: array of char;
var machineindex: integer;
var product: array of integer;
var quality: array of integer;
var min, number: integer;
var i, j, extra: integer;
var myTable: array[1..7,1..10,1..2] of integer;

begin
i:= 0;
j:= 0;
number := 0;
min := 5;
extra := 5;
SETLENGTH( machine, min );
SETLENGTH( product, min );
SETLENGTH( quality, min );
writeln('Input Machine ID ( A, B, C, D, E, F or G ) ');
readln(machine[number] );
while (machine[number] <> '*') do
 begin
  while ( ORD( machine[number] ) < 65 ) or ( ORD( machine[number] ) > 71 ) do
   begin
    writeln('Input Invalid. Please try again.');
    readln(machine[number] );
   end;
   machineindex := (ORD(machine[number])-65);
   writeln('Input Product Number ( 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 or 9 ) ');
   readln(product[number] );
   while ( product[number] < 0 ) or ( product[number] > 9 ) do
    begin
     writeln('Input Invalid. Please try again.');
      readln(product[number] );
    end;
    writeln('Quality Control Check. Input 0 for GOOD or 1 for BAD.');
    readln(quality[number] );
    while ( quality[number] <> 0 ) and ( quality[number] <> 1 ) do
     begin
      writeln('Input Invalid. Please try again.');
      readln(quality[number] );
     end;
     myTable[machineindex,(product[number]),(quality[number])] := myTable[machineindex,(product[number]),(quality[number])] + 1;
     number := number + 1;
     if number = LENGTH(machine) then
      begin
       SETLENGTH(machine, LENGTH(machine)+extra);
       SETLENGTH(product, LENGTH(product)+extra);
       SETLENGTH(quality, LENGTH(quality)+extra)
      end;
      writeln('Input Machine ID ( A, B, C, D, E, F or G ) ');
      readln(machine[number] );
end;
writeln('  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9');
for i := 0 to 6 do
 begin
  write(CHR(65+i),' ');
  for j := 0 to 9 do
    begin
      write(myTable[i,j,0], ' ');
    end;
  writeln('');
end;
writeln();
writeln('  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9');
for i := 0 to 6 do
 begin
  write(CHR(65+i),' ');
  for j := 0 to 9 do
   begin
    write(myTable[i,j,1], ' ');
   end;
  writeln('');
 end;

writeln('');
writeln('');
writeln('EXIT');
readln;
end.
```

I have this program (which a kind soul has already helped me with) and it prints out two tables at the end.

The first of the two tables works perfectly. The second does not. I don't understand where the difference comes from.

The two tables should print out like this if the user gives no input other than a * at the very start:

---0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

A 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

B 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

C 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

D 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

E 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

F 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

G 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

However no matter what I do, the second tables gives this as output:

---0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

A 0 5 0 1 0 0 0 7 0 5

B 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

C 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

D 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

E 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

F 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

G 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? There must be something causing this but to me it looks like there's no problem in the code. I do get a "range check error while evaluating constants" but that's in the code of the table that works as it should.
I also get a warning that "myTable is not initialised" but surely if it were that that was the problem then both tables would be wrong?

EDIT: I changed the declaration of myTable to:
    var myTable: array[0..6,0..9,0..1] of integer;
from
    var myTable: array[1..7,1..10,1..2] of integer;

It seems to have solved the problem, other than the "myTable is not initialised" warning.

Comment: No, the warning is correct. You do not initialize the contents of `myArray` if the user inputs nothing but `*`, and therefore the contents is whatever random data is in that area of memory. *Random* means *you can't depend on what you'll find there*. Always initialize variables that are not managed types, and always pay attention to warnings - 99.9% of the time the compiler is smarter than we are when it's analyzing the code.

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply

I changed the line `var myTable: array[1..7,1..10,1..2] of integer;` to `var myTable: array[0..6,0..9,0..1] of integer;` to match the other arrays. Now it works fine.    I am still getting the myTable is not initialised warning, but not the other one. However it's doing it perfectly now.

Comment: You only removed the warning related to the range check error. You haven't fixed the problem itself. You ignored what I wrote.

Comment: Sorry I didn't ignore it. I had already done it and was coming back to update when I saw your comment. I'm not sure how to initialise the array myTable, I've been googling.

Comment: I altered the code to include a triple nested for loop which initialised myTable and got rid of the warning. Thank you.

Comment: Well, of course changing your declaration to have `0` based indices versus `1` based will work because your `for` loops index starting at `0` (*e.g.*, `for i := 0 to 6 do...`). If your `for` loops indexed starting at `1` (*e.g.*, `for i := 1 to 7 do...`), then your original declaration would work.